# Redirect to a new page using Browser or Tab Close Event in (Chrome, Firefox and IE) All of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, google-chrome

Please do not mark this as duplicate, as this is not being answered completely in any single post. also no recent working solution for latest browsers is found.
My Question is as under, i am using Asp.net C#, and the code should work on client-side preferably.

1. Is it Possible to Catch Browser/Tab Close Event for Non IE Browsers (ex. Chrome, Firefox) Current Versions [Version 81+ for Chrome (64-bit)], and Execute navigate to logout page.

The code which i tried for Chrome primarily is as below.

```
            window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = 'this is cuctom message';
            window.location.href = "~/logout/Logout.aspx"; 
        });
```

Now when i use above code in IE, it gives me message like [image: IE Message on Tab Close click]
the problem which i am facing with above code is.

1. On Every link click this message is called in IE, along with tab close too, and i want to call this message only on tab or browser close.
2. for Chrome though, above code is called only on link navigation, **but not redirected to logout page**, and not on browser close.

I am stuck in this activity, with no way forward, can anyone please help me out with a way towards solution to this issue.

Comment: This isn't possible, as it would be too easy to abuse

Comment: Hi @Milney, thanks for answering, i tried almost all the possible solutions on internet, although on IE, above event fires on browser and tab close, but do you mean to say that on other browsers like "Chrome" this is not doable. If so, "then what can be the alternative way to logout the user on Tab or Browser close in these browsers?"
I am currently relying on Session_End Event of Global.asax, but that takes away the precious 10 mins or so from the time of closing the browser to logout the user.

Any wise thought will be appreciated.
Thanks for commenting.

Comment: Your best bet would be using something like websockets or doing a 'heartbeat' AJAX call every so often and detecting when they stop. These still have caveats like scalability issues and what to do if the same user has multiple tabs or windows open on the same site. What are you actually trying to accomplish with this? There is a probably a better way to achieve or invalidate the need for your end goal rather than trying to get this to work perfectly

Comment: Hi @Milney, Thanks you so much for replying, your thought gave me the idea of using signalR in this scenario, i'll try and implement this in our project.
My Aim is to achieve Concurrent Logins restriction in our project as stated in above Question, doing that one scenario is like--> if the user clicks on browser close rather than logout, then unless the session_timeout is attained, the user is not released. so the login licence remains underutilized till then.
So my thought was to call Logout page functionality or Redirect to logout page if the user tries to close browser or tab.